How to install LeanCopilot?
I already read https://github.com/lean-dojo/LeanCopilot?tab=readme-ov-file#using-lean-copilot-in-your-project.
I'm working with Visual Studio Code (VSCode) under Windows.
Where should I type in the commands?
It seems the description fails with the current versions of Lean: we don't have a file lakefile.lean in the project directory anymore.

"we don't have a file lakefile.lean in the project directory anymore" it seems that you have a broken project. Please refer to starting a Lean project to see how to instruct lake to generate the various files you might be missing, including a bare lakefile.lean.

@jthulhu lake new myprojectname math now defaults to a .toml file instead of a lakefile.lean file.  If you want a lakefile you can use lake new myprojectname math.lean but I don’t know of how to convert an existing project easily to the old lakefile format.

@JasonRute ah, indeed. And, it appears that LeanCopilot's README has also changed to take that into account, so now tthere are he instructions on how to set it up with the toml format.
